# When to use the various flagging options?

Tags: discussion, flags

When flagging a question, you are offered these options<sup>1</sup>:

> - **spam**
>   *Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.*
> - **rude or abusive**
>   *A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.*
> - **needs improvement**
>   *This question needs updates from the author in order to be answered well or belongs on another Stack Exchange site.*
> - **a duplicate**
>   *This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*
> - **in need of moderator intervention**
>   *A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*

When flagging an answer, you are offered these options:

> - **spam**
>   *Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.*
> - **rude or abusive**
>   *A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.*
> - **not an answer**
>   *This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.*
> - **in need of moderator intervention**
>   *A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*

Currently, flag counts are low overall, yet downvotes and criticism in comments of poorly crafted posts are common. According the current moderators at time of this post the comments often strongly indicate a deletion or post banner is needed, but there are no flags on the post. This leaves the moderators to act apparently unilaterally. Thus, critical commenting and downvoting *without also flagging* is sometimes inconsistent and should be corrected.

In looking at the options available, and with the above information fresh in my mind, I realize that I don't feel I have clear guidance on when to use which flags. Just minutes ago, I went to flag an old answer for deletion, but when confronted with the options, didn't know which to choose and almost decided to not flag at all.

We need clear guidance on when to use these flags. Going though each item above and noting what happens behind the scenes after a flag is raised will go a long way in helping users use them. After that, noting where any major site policies fit in would round out the problem quite nicely.

---

<sub>1. Options offered do vary slightly based on your reputation, but they are roughly the same, with the "Should be closed" option offered for those without the close vote privilege.</sub>

Comment: The most trouble gives the R/A flag, that *is* abused, mainly on MetaSE. Why should I care whether 'a reasonable person' would think anything at all. That's a terrible way to explain the flag and pre-emptive of the now per broken-CoC reasoning mandatory political correctness: anyone may feel attacked at any time for any reason they see fit and is then as per these rules the prime arbiter of the correctness of that claim. Although it's then said that mods would weigh that on case-by-case basis, to avoid "lawyering". If we could formulate a better version and procedure than prevalent over there?

Comment: The second trouble-maker is  'duplicate' as this is usually handled across SE as 'we close these when we spot spot them' *'in favour of the one with better answers'* which is clearly against any logic behind the actual phrasing employed, as such actual behaviour may run counter the 'before' (+ plus the added jargon of 'merge' for marking a dupe); it makes nosense to mark a Q a dupe if the traget is younger.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: I just read through the entire [CoC](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/conduct) word-for-word, and I could not find *any* evidence that the complainant is "the prime arbiter of the correctness of that claim." Please cite your sources or retract your claim.